# Write full type information to a file

Tags: typescript

I have a web application where the user can download the current state and upload it on another computer. This state is versioned. Now when the user uploads a state with an old version, I update the state to the current version.
This update function I want to be typed. This means that I have to have a type for every version. Since the state is a complex combination of multiple different types, I cannot simply copy it. If I would do this, I would also have to copy every type the state-type is depending on or else when I change a subtype, I will also change an old version type.
Because of this I want to automatically copy the state-type, including with the subtypes.
Is there a tool or way to write them to a single file preferably so that the only exported type is the copied state-type? This would prevent to import the other types and it would be future-proof

I've tried to compile it with `declaration` and `emitDeclarationOnly` but this did not resolve in one single file